# Alignement of Table in TabularX

Tags: tabularx

Could somebody please help me with the poor alignment and extra-spaces in the third row of this table?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering 
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXc@{}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Known facts} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Open questions} & Objectives \\ \midrule
        Ply-strength depends on ply-thickness (also known as in-situ effect) & There is no evidence of the in-situ effect under transverse shear & \multirow{10}{*}{1} \\
        &  There is controversy about which damage mechanism triggers the other  &  \\
        Out-of-plane loads induce  shear cracks and delaminations & There is controversy about which damage  mechanism   penalizes  the components' load-carrying capacity &  \\
        & There is no clear evidence of how ply-thickness affects damage sequence evolution &  \\ \midrule
        Thin-plies increase several in-plane mechanical properties  because of the in-situ effect & \multirow{4}{=}{There is little information on how ply-thickness affects thin laminates' impact response} & \multirow{4}{*}{2} \\
        Thin-plies display brittle failure mechanisms &  &  \\ \midrule
        Interleaving polyamide veils with a relatively high fibre areal weight enhances impact resistance, tolerance and interlaminar fracture toughness & Few studies incorporate veils with low fibre areal weight & \multirow{8}{*}{3$\&$4} \\
        The improvement comes with a penalty of tensile and compressive properties & No study toughens thin-ply laminates &  \\ & Few studies connect veil fibre architecture and mechanical properties & \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}
```

Comment: hi, Could you provide us a MWE, please ?

Comment: Code is attached!

Comment: you should extend your table code to complete small document (mwe: minimal working example) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

i merge last three rows to one. beside this i made some small changes in table format and add document preamble  as i like to have (your is not known):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}LLc@{}}
        \toprule
\thead{Known facts}
    &   \thead{Open questions}
        &   \thead{Objectives}   \\
        \midrule
Ply-strength depends on ply-thickness (also known as in-situ effect)
    &   There is no evidence of the in-situ effect under transverse shear
        & \multirow{10}{*}{1} \\
    &  There is controversy about which damage mechanism triggers the other
        &  \\
Out-of-plane loads induce  shear cracks and delaminations
    &   There is controversy about which damage  mechanism   penalizes  the components' load-carrying capacity  &  \\
        &   There is no clear evidence of how ply-thickness affects damage sequence evolution              &  \\
    \midrule
Thin-plies increase several in-plane mechanical properties  because of the in-situ effect
    & \multirow{5}{=}{There is little information on how ply-thickness affects thin laminates' impact response}
        & \multirow{5}{*}{2}                \\
Thin-plies display brittle failure mechanisms
    &   &                                   \\
    \midrule
Interleaving polyamide veils with a relatively high fibre areal weight enhances impact resistance, tolerance and interlaminar fracture toughness

\smallskip
The improvement comes with a penalty of tensile and compressive properties
    &   Few studies incorporate veils with low fibre areal weight

        \smallskip
        No study toughens thin-ply laminates

        \smallskip
        Few studies connect veil fibre architecture and mechanical properties
        & \multirow{6}{*}{3$\&$4} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, but why is not the text justified now?

Comment: @Santi, because i liked such formatting of text. if you like to have justified, replace ` in column type options  `L` with `X`.